# Heroku worker sleeping when web process on same app sleeps

Tags: javascript, heroku, ejs, discord.js

I have been trying to run a worker and a web process through heroku, but when the web process sleeps, the worker stops. The worker is a discord bot btw, so its very easy to test it when it is asleep

procfile

```
web: node ./dist/webserver.js
worker: node ./dist/index.js
```

Comment: You could ping the server using a third party cron

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping Worker dynos do not sleep. Your worker is probably erroring that's why it stops. You should make the worker work independently from the web worker and use a database in the middle. The web dyno sleeping should have no impact on the worker dyno.